# Writing Testcases for google cloud endpoints API written on top of django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using google cloud endpoints on my django app to provide RESTful services. All API services are working perfectly. Now, it's the time for writing testcases. So I wrote this.

`TestPOIList.py`

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
import endpoints
import webtest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from .queries import CategoryQuery
from .queries import PointOfInterestQuery
from .models import PointOfInterest
from .api.internal.point_of_interest import PointOfInterests


class Test(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.setup_env(current_version_id='testbed.version')
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_all_stubs()

        self.category_a = CategoryQuery.create_category_by_name('Museums')
        self.poi = PointOfInterestQuery.create_new_poi(name='bhavan', category=self.category_a,
                                                       place='hdgf', phone='3454545', email='dsg@jhgs.com'
                                                       )

        app = endpoints.api_server([PointOfInterests], restricted=False)
        self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    # Test the handler.
    def test_should_return_list_of_pois(self):
        msg = {}
        resp = self.testapp.post_json('/_ah/spi/PointOfInterests.get_list', msg, status='*')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(resp.json['pois']['name'], 'Saravan bhavan')
```

I tried running the above code with `python manage.py test` , `python manage.py test appname`. But it won't work.

I also tried [`django-nose`](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose). It also fails to test even a single test case. Output displayed after running `python manage.py test` was,

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

So it fails to run my first testcase. Pls give some suggestions.

**Edit:**

Changing the file name to `testpoilist` finds the testcase but it fails to import appengine related modules. And resulted in many `import` errors. So I tried running `nosetests` but it shows,

```
$ nosetests -q -w src/ --with-gae
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/bin/nosetests", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_exit())
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 121, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 145, in parseArgs
    self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/config.py", line 346, in configure
    self.plugins.configure(options, self)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 284, in configure
    cfg(options, config)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nosegae.py", line 85, in configure
    import appengine_config
  File "/home/gemini/projects/sample-backend/src/appengine_config.py", line 22, in <module>
    vendor.add('lib')
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/vendor/__init__.py", line 44, in add
    'No such virtualenv or site directory' % path)
ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory
```

**Edit 2:**
After changing `vendor.add('lib')` to something specified in the below answer, I got this error.

```
$ nosetests -q -w src/ --with-gae
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/bin/nosetests", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_exit())
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 121, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 207, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 62, in run
    test(result)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 177, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 224, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 177, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 224, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 177, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 217, in run
    for test in self._tests:
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 372, in _get_wrapped_tests
    for test in self._get_tests():
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 99, in _get_tests
    for test in self.test_generator:
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 191, in loadTestsFromDir
    entry_path, discovered=True)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 433, in loadTestsFromName
    discovered=discovered)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 354, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.extend(self.loadTestsFromDir(module_path))
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 191, in loadTestsFromDir
    entry_path, discovered=True)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 433, in loadTestsFromName
    discovered=discovered)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 354, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.extend(self.loadTestsFromDir(module_path))
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 183, in loadTestsFromDir
    entry_path, discovered=True)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 427, in loadTestsFromName
    address=addr.totuple())])
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 427, in __call__
    return self.makeSuite(tests, context, **kw)
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 482, in makeSuite
    for ancestor in self.ancestry(context):
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 453, in ancestry
    yield resolve_name('.'.join(ancestors))
  File "/home/gemini/.virtualenvs/sample/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 322, in resolve_name
    obj = getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'failure'
```

**Edit 3:**

I also tried running django test using `python manage.py test` . But it shows,

```
ERROR: src.tests.api.internal.test_poi_list (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: src.tests.api.internal.test_poi_list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/backend/src/tests/api/internal/test_poi_list.py", line 9, in <module>
    from guide.api.internal.point_of_interest import PointOfInterests
  File "/home/gemini/projects/backend/src/cityguide/api/internal/point_of_interest.py", line 12, in <module>
    from guide.api.common import GuideInternalAPI
  File "/home/gemini/projects/backend/src/guide/api/common.py", line 9, in <module>
    GuideInternalAPI = endpoints.api(name='GuideInternalAPI',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'api'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Seems I'm almost close to that. `PYTHONPATH` variable shows the google_appengine sdk path.

Comment: Do you have a separate settings file for test? And, what is the name of this file which have these tests?

Comment: No, there is only one settings.py file.

Comment: Django uses `DiscoverRunner` by default to run test suites and it follows `test*.py` pattern to get the files which have unit tests. Could you change the filename accordingly and test again?

Comment: Did this problem get resolved?

Comment: @AKS check my update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem by appending project's `lib` folder to system path variable.

So part of your `manage.py` file should look like,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
    sys.path.append(sys.path[0] + os.path.sep + 'lib')
```

Then run the test through django. Don't do a `nosetest`.

```
python manage.py test
```

Note that your test files should have a name starts with `test`, so that django would consider it as a test file. One of my test file would look like,

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
import endpoints
import webtest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from project.queries import CategoryQuery
from project.api.internal.categories import Categories


class Test(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.setup_env(current_version_id='testbed.version')
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_all_stubs()

        self.category_a = CategoryQuery.create_category_by_name('Museums')

        app = endpoints.api_server([Categories], restricted=False)
        self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    # Test the handler.
    def test_should_return_list_of_pois(self):
        msg = {}
        resp = self.testapp.post_json('/_ah/spi/Categories.get_list', msg, status='*')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(resp.json['categories'][0]['name'], 'Museums')
```

Answer (score 3):

In `appengine_config.py` Change `vendor.add('lib')` to `vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))`. The path your tests are being executed from aren't relative to `lib` so you are seeing that error. Don't forget to import `os`.

Comment: now I got a different traceback.pls check my update.

Comment: That has something to do with your tests I guess. I don't see any code in your post that would trigger it though.

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem on my own. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I answered your original question. If you truly answered your other two edits by yourself then you should post a new answer with the solution and mark it as accepted it so other people can find it later on.